# Is there a way to push multiple inputs into the same Db column in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried searching for something similar to the question above but no luck.

I have a one to many relationship between a series and videos table. Inside the videos table I have title and url to the video.

The issue i am having is that, i am using jquery to add multiple rows containing title and url.

I tried pushing the title and url to the videos table on the database. There's no problem when pushing one input but when i have many title and url, the code breaks.

I have also tried using createMany but it can only add an array of one input. I can't get it to add both title and url.

```
$data = \request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'vimeo_id' => 'required',
            'episode_number' => 'required'
        ]);


        $pricourse->videos()->createMany($data);
```

After i dd the data in the browser i got the following

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "82k5RnVcdzSkPoOnDYeYipuRqAcJqhXzcWAx3RwW"
  "title" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Angles of Elevation"
    1 => "English 2"
  ]
  "vimeo_id" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "12343"
    1 => "12343"
  ]
  "episode_number" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
]
```

Any  help will be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You can add with json structure column with the key., but why you dont use model relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered i was not passing the data from the hmtl page properly. I made a few changes to it.

```
<input type="text" name="videos[0][title]">
<input type="text" name="videos[0][vimeo_id]">
<input type="text" name="videos[0][episode_number]">

<input type="text" name="videos[1][title]">
<input type="text" name="videos[1][vimeo_id]">
<input type="text" name="videos[1][episode_number]">
```

My controller code goes below

```
$data = \request()->validate([
            'videos.*.title' => 'required',
            'videos.*.vimeo_id' => 'required',
            'videos.*.episode_number' => 'required'
        ]);

$pricourse->videos()->createMany($data['videos']);
```

All i had to do was pass $data['videos'] inside createMany

Thank you all for your help. It served as a pointer

Answer (score 0):

`createMany()` is the way to go as far as I can understand. You are probably doing it wrong.

Here is an example :

```php
$videosToCreate = [
    [
        'title' => 'title number 1',
        'url' => 'some url number 1'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'title number 2',
        'url' => 'some url number 2'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'title etc...',
        'url' => 'some url etc...'
    ]
];

$this->videos()->createMany($videosToCreate);
```

We cannot help you if you do not share any code though.